# Anti-commutator of Dirac matrices

Tags: dirac-matrices, anticommutator

Consider $$ \beta = \begin{pmatrix} \mathbf{1} & 0 \\ 0 & -\mathbf{1} \end{pmatrix},\quad \alpha_i = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & \mathbf{\sigma}_i \\ \mathbf{\sigma}_i&0 \end{pmatrix}.$$ The Dirac matrices $\gamma_i$ are then of the form $\gamma^0 = \beta, \gamma^i=\beta \alpha_i$. In my notes, I have the following expression: $$ \{ \gamma^{\mu},\gamma^{\nu}\} = 2 g^{\mu\nu} \mathbf{1},$$ where $g^{\mu\nu}=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 &0 &0 \\ 0&-1&0&0\\0&0&-1&0\\0&0&0&-1\end{pmatrix}$. This expression is shown by considering $\{\gamma^i,\gamma^j\}$, which equals $-2\delta_{ij}\mathbf{1}$ by direct verification and the relation $\{\mathbf{\sigma}_i,\mathbf{\sigma}_j\}=2\delta_{ij}\mathbf{1}$.  Now, I don't see how this proves the first anticommutation relation. My main issue is that I don't understand how $\{ \gamma^{\mu},\gamma^{\nu}\}$ looks like? How can this anticommutator be written in terms of $\{\gamma^i,\gamma^j\}$?

Generally, how to 'visualize' the (anti-)commutator of two 4-vectors?

Answer (score 1):

In order to prove $\{\gamma^\mu,\gamma^{\nu}\} = 2g^{\mu\nu}\mathbf{1}$ one only has to know that $\mu=(0,i)$ with $i=1,\ldots 3$ and check

$\{\gamma^0,\gamma^0\} = 2g^{00}\mathbf{1} \quad \text{,}\quad \{\gamma^0,\gamma^{i}\} = 2g^{0i}\mathbf{1} \quad \text{and}\quad \{\gamma^i,\gamma^{j}\} = 2g^{ij}\mathbf{1}$

As you have already $\{\gamma^i,\gamma^{j}\} = 2g^{ij}\mathbf{1}$ one only has to prove $2(\gamma^0)^2 \equiv2\beta ^2=2\cdot\mathbf{1}$ and $\{\beta ,\beta\alpha_i\} =\mathbf{0}$

This can be done by computation with the matrices given in the post.